# How to implement handmade features in a Keras Sequential model?

Tags: python, keras, feature-engineering

I wanted to know how to implement my handmade features in my Keras model.
Below I have some code where the embedding_matrix is the Stanford Glove NLP dataset.

```
def BidLstm(maxlen, max_features, embed_size, embedding_matrix):
   inp = Input(shape=(maxlen, ))
   x = Embedding(max_features, embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix],
                 trainable=False)(inp)
   x = Bidirectional(LSTM(300, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25,
                          recurrent_dropout=0.25))(x)
   x = Attention(maxlen)(x)
   x = Dense(256, activation="relu")(x)
   x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
   x = Dense(6, activation="sigmoid")(x)
   model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
```

I want to implement some extra features (preferably numpy array of features) into my keras model.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

Very interesting  question , I am  wondering if there  are nough skilled  data science  entusiast   that  could   answer this question , because I am  interested in simmilar stuff as well.
Congratulations  for this  question  man